# How to set per process swapiness for linux?

Tags: linux, process, swap

`/proc/sys/vm/swappiness` is nice, but I want a knob that is per process like `/proc/$PID/oom_adj`. So that I can make certain processes less likely than others to have any of their pages swapped out. Unlike `memlock()`, this doesn't prevent a program from being swapped out. And like `nice`, the user by default can't make their programs less likely, but only more likely to get swapped. I think I had to call this `/proc/$PID/swappiness_adj`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can configure swappiness per cgroup:

http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt

http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt

For an easier introduction to cgroups, with examples, see

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch01.html

Comment: Beware, that, according to the RedHat guide, enabling memory-cgroup uses additional memory, 40 byte per page.  Consider hugepages to reduce the number of pages in this context, see https://wiki.debian.org/Hugepages

Answer (score 2):

I would like to extend [Šimon Tóth's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10227/53245) with a real life solution that I have developed. I think that it deserves a separate answer.

#### RedHat 7 - cgroups v1 and systemd

As only [since RedHat 8 the cgroups v2 are supported](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/world-domination-cgroups-rhel-8-welcome-cgroups-v2), we need to use cgroups v1 here.

The [official guide suggests](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/resource_management_guide/sec-modifying_control_groups#sec-Modifying_Unit_Files) adding a `ExecStartPost` that changes memory settings for your service, but it does not work until you make another change that will make `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice` available.

So I ended up with adding this to my service unit file, assuming that the service name is `example`:

```
# the first entry is here only to make /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice path
# available for the next entry
MemoryLimit=64G
# this entry actually effectively disables swap for the service
ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c \
              "echo 0 > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/example.service/memory.swappiness"
```