# how to make a memory hungry application cause swap slowness only to itself?

Tags: swap, ram, limit, application, hang

I have 6GB RAM and 10GB swap. Some applications dare to consume/allocate/use about 5GB to 6GB of RAM.

When the memory completely fills out, the whole system hangs for 1 to 2 minutes to swap all inactive (and active) appplications, what is really troublesome because to access again some simple applications that consume less than 100MB, I have to wait about 10s to it be put on RAM again (well, all that is how I see it works out of my usage experience).

So, my goal is: put that single application under leash, restrict it to keep the whole system fast and stable.

Comment: A memory ulimit is out of the question?

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes, I think the deal is to limit the RAM usage, and make such hungry application go to swap before all others, so I would give to that application only 2GB of RAM and everything else of it would go to swap.

Comment: yes, it has to do with swapiness, but in a sense that it must swap anything beyond 2GB of RAM (and not just be more likely to swap). The question [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10214/how-to-set-per-process-swapiness-for-linux) is not how I would ask it, but the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10227/30352) there, about memory cgroup limit seems to be the way to go, thx!